# Remove or disable Monday and Tuesday from datepicker in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, datepicker

Im my application in Sharepoint Online I need remove or disable tuesday and monday from datepicker, it is possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Insert a CEWP on your Calendar Page and refer it to the below script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var oTable = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
if (oTable != null) {

for (i = 0; i < oTable.length; i++)
{
 var table = oTable.item(i);
 if (table.className == "ms-acal-month")
 {
  for (var c = 0; c < table.rows.length; c++)
  {
  if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 8)
  {
   table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
   table.rows[c].cells[1].style.display = "none";
   table.rows[c].cells[7].style.display = "none";
  }
  else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 7)
  {
   table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
   table.rows[c].cells[6].style.display = "none";
  }
  else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 6)
  {
   table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
   table.rows[c].cells[5].style.display = "none";
  }
  else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 2)
  {
   table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
   table.rows[c].cells[1].style.display = "none";
    }
   }
  }
 }
} 
 });

//For month view
function month(){

var oTable = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
if (oTable != null) {

for (i = 0; i < oTable.length; i++)
{
var table = oTable.item(i);
if (table.className == "ms-acal-month")
{
for (var c = 0; c < table.rows.length; c++)
{
if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 8)
{
 table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
 table.rows[c].cells[1].style.display = "none";
 table.rows[c].cells[7].style.display = "none";
 }
 else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 7)
 {
  table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
  table.rows[c].cells[6].style.display = "none";
  }
  else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 6)
  {
  table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
  table.rows[c].cells[5].style.display = "none";
  }
  else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 2)
  {
   table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
   table.rows[c].cells[1].style.display = "none";
   }

   }
  }
 }
}
 }
       // For Week View
       function week(){

      var oTable = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
      if (oTable != null) {

      for (i = 0; i < oTable.length; i++)
      {
      var table = oTable.item(i);
      if (table.className == "ms-acal-detail")
      {
      for (var c = 0; c < table.rows.length; c++)
      {
      if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 8)
      {
      table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
      table.rows[c].cells[1].style.display = "none";
      table.rows[c].cells[7].style.display = "none";
      }
      else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 7)
      {
      table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
      table.rows[c].cells[6].style.display = "none";
      }
      else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 6)
      {
      table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
      table.rows[c].cells[5].style.display = "none";
      }
      else if (table.rows[c].cells.length == 2)
      {
      table.rows[c].cells[0].style.display = "none";
      table.rows[c].cells[1].style.display = "none";
      }

           }
          }
         }
        }
       }



      $( "#WPQ2_nav_prev_a" ).click(function() {
       month();
      })
      $( ".ms-picker-table" ).click(function() {
      month();
      })
      $( "#WPQ2_nav_next_a" ).click(function() {
      month();
      })
      setInterval(function () { month()}, -10000);
      setInterval(function () { month()}, -10000);
      setInterval(function () { week()}, -10000);
```

Comment: Hi Ravi, this solutions is to hide the week days in calendar, I need restrict days in datepicker.

Comment: Hi Ravi, this solutions is to hide the week days in calendar, I need restrict days in datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

The SharePoint Date Picker control does not support this.

You should use the jQuery Date Picker control.

Information about how to disable specific days in JQuery datepicker:

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/876970/how-to-disable-specific-days-in-JQuery-datepicker